# Return Select option value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to return and output to a variable a select option that the user selects in a dropdown menu below.

```
<h3>Cake Size</h3>
<select id="cakeSize">
    <option value="6">6" Cake</option>
    <option value="8">8" Cake</option>
    <option value="10">10" Cake</option>
    <option value="12">12" Cake</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="calc">Calculate</button>
```

I want to get `6/8/10/12` into a variable.

```
const calc = document.getElementById('calc');
let cakeSize = document.getElementById('cakeSize');
let value = cakeSize.value;

calc.addEventListener('click', function test(){
  return alert(value);
});
```

Would like to do this initially using a button event listener to trigger the collection of the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `alert` the selected value, use `alert(cakeSize.value)`. `let value = cakeSize.value;` will have only the initial `select` value.

```js
let cakeSize = document.getElementById('cakeSize');
// let value = cakeSize.value;

calc.addEventListener('click', function test() {
  return alert(cakeSize.value);
});
```

```html
<h3>Cake Size</h3>
<select id="cakeSize">
  <option value="6">6" Cake</option>
  <option value="8">8" Cake</option>
  <option value="10">10" Cake</option>
  <option value="12">12" Cake</option>
</select>


<button type="button" id="calc">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Many thanks, That works, now I require to extract the value into the global scope so I can mess about with the functions result. This is the bit that previously confused me.